# How to do a hbase range scan?

Tags: hbase

I have a hbase table with the rowkey like row1, row2, row3 .... and rowN , what I want is get the rows with rowkey from row100 to row200 , how to write the query clause or design the hbase table to make the query faster?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This will work for ASCII row keys. Note that ENDROW is exclusive.

The following should be a good start:

```
 scan 'mytable', {STARTROW => 'row100', ENDROW => 'row201'}
```

In Java (see [apidocs](https://hbase.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/client/Scan.html#Scan-byte:A-byte:A-)):

```
Scan scan = new Scan(Bytes.ToBytes("row100"),Bytes.toBytes("row201"); 
scan.setFilter(colFilter);
scan.setOtherStuff...

ResultScanner scanner = table.getScanner(scan);
for (Result result = scanner.next(); result != null; result = scanner.next()) {
    ....
}
```

Table design should probably be a separate question and you should add way more information about your data, access patterns, and other needs.

Comment: how about if there is no number in the row key, such as the format  of row keys are AAA,BBB,BBC,DDD.... , so we don't know the rowkey in position 100 and 200, so how to get the rows between them?

Comment: For STARTROW that's not a problem. For ENDROW you can use the first next char after the last one you need. Take a look at: http://www.ascii-code.com/ This can be done programmatically as well.

Answer (score 0):

Since HBase 2, use:

```
Scan scan = new Scan().withStartRow(Bytes.ToBytes("row100")).withStopRow(Bytes.toBytes("row201"));
```